# Ошибка в aiogram Message.reply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replay_markup'

Tags: python, aiogram

Код:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['inline'])
async def info(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Site', url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvPaua-oC08&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFUev1gp9yEwmwcy8SicqKbt&index=8'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('her', callback_data='her')) # здесь строка callback_data='her' отправляет текст her
    await message.reply('Hello', replay_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback(call):
    await call.message.answer(call.data)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['replay'])
async def replay(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('sirt'))
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('set'))
    await message.answer('hello', replay_markup=markup)
```

Ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("Message.reply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replay_markup'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates 
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Админ\Desktop\Телега\Exception\MainAio.py", line 19, in info
    await message.reply('Hello', replay_markup=markup)
TypeError: Message.reply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replay_markup'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будьте внимательней. У вас ошибка в слове reply - не должно быть буквы а.
Исправленный код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['inline'])
async def info(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Site', url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvPaua-oC08&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFUev1gp9yEwmwcy8SicqKbt&index=8'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('her', callback_data='her')) # здесь строка callback_data='her' отправляет текст her
    await message.reply('Hello', reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback(call):
    await call.message.answer(call.data)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['replay'])
async def replay(message: types.Message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('sirt'))
    markup.add(types.KeyboardButton('set'))
    await message.answer('hello', reply_markup=markup)
```